# Application Context not injected in an `@Configuration` annotated class

Tags: java, spring

I have a setup like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(MyBean.class);
    }
}
```

Soon as I launch my Application, Spring tries to create `myBean` even before injecting `applicationContext`. As the latter is `null`, it will cause a `NullPointerException` in the method `myBean()`.

Strangely, injecting the Application Context works in some other `@Configuration` classes, but not in the one mentioned above.

Is there a way force the injection of `applicationContext` before the method `myBean()` is called?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This happens under very rare conditions.

Comment: My configuration class looks like this except the variable names have been exchanged. However, finding out the exact components, configuration files or test class runners that participate to the problem could take days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have the guarantee that the fields declared with `@Autowired` be always loaded before  the invocation of the methods declared with `@Bean` .

To ensure that the `ApplicationContext` object is valued, you could  make your configuration class implement `ApplicationContextAware`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private ApplicationContext context;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
      this.context = context;
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Spring `@Configuration` classes apparently need a no-argument-constructor, however, implementing `ApplicationContextAware` works. Still don't understand what is going on.

Comment: About the no arg constructor, I never tried but t is surprising enough that the doc shows a arg constructor example : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html